# Core data creates an sqlite file with no tables

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios4, xcode4.6

I am creating an ios application with xcode 4.6.1 which uses core data to save data in the database, i have provided the deployment target as ios 4.3 and the base sdk is set to latest 6.1.

The place where i am stuck is when i run the application on ios 4.3 i see that my sqlite file is created but contains no tables in it. I have wrote no special code here and every thing is by default taken care in the app delegate, i came across few post where other developers have said to

```
 NSURL *modelURL =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"StudentData" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

use "mom" above but i even did that and it seems that every time in ios 4.3 this issue pops up, i have also tried and reset my simulator lots of time but nothing seems to be working and i do require ios4.3 support so please let me know what's going on here and what do i need to do.

I also tried printing

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[self managedObjectModel]);
```

but it's not nil

Please note their is no mistake in the name of the files here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i got this working what i did was ran the application and saw that it created the sqlite file but with no tables but when i tried to insert the data in the database with ios 4.3 then the data got inserted and tables were created surprisingly it did not make any sense to me but i got this working without changing anything in the code.

Answer (score 0):

NSBundle *modelWrapper = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StudentData" ofType:@"momd"]];

NSString *modelPath = [modelWrapper pathForResource:@"StudentData" ofType:@"mom"];

managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath]];

Answer (score 0):

By default in Mac OS you don't have write permission.

From terminal go to the path where you have stored your StudentData file and then write this command `chmod 777`.

It will allow you to write data in files.